# VeeValidate 3 setErrors error message for current input change

Tags: vue.js, vee-validate

I have validation on two inputs. And I want to set the error message on two inputs using the setErrors() method of vee-validate the same time when I change data in the input. 
Problem: Don't show message error on current input change data 
 
Expect Result: I want to see the message error on two inputs.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <ValidationObserver ref="adad" v-slot="{ passes }">
      <ValidationProvider name="min" mode="lazy" rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
        <input type="number" v-model.number="minValue" @change="handleErrors">
        <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
      </ValidationProvider>
      <ValidationProvider name="max" mode="lazy" rules="required" v-slot="{ errors }">
        <input type="number" v-model.number="maxValue" @change="handleErrors">
        <span>{{ errors[0] }}</span>
      </ValidationProvider>
      <button @click="passes(handleErrors)">Validate</button>
    </ValidationObserver>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { extend } from "vee-validate";

extend("between", {
  params: ["min", "max"],
  validate(value, { min, max }) {
    return value >= min && value <= max;
  },
  message: "This field value must be between {min} and {max}"
});

export default {
  data: () => ({
    minValue: 0,
    value: 1,
    maxValue: 10
  }),
  methods: {
    handleErrors() {
      console.log("====> handleErrors");
      this.$refs.adad.setErrors({
        min: "hello world",
        max: "hello world"
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```